# Unified write filter serving mode

Tags: windows, command-line

Right now, we want to remotely manage Windows updates on devices via endpoint manager.

Because we have UWF enabled (this blocks any changes to the machine), the endpoint manager forced updates will not work. We must run CMD as administrator and run the script [uwfmgr servicing enable] or [uwfmgr.exe servicing enable]. This works fine, but right now we must do it individually on each machine.

The overall goal right now – is to get ‘uwfmgr servicing enable” cmd script to work remotely. Then we can move onto the next steps which is adding more complexity to it such as getting the machine to auto reboot etc. But right now, sole focus is remote managing these windows updates.

any idea how can this be done? Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are the two [Microsoft-recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/customize/unified-write-filter#features) ways of remotely managing UWF:

1. Use the [UWF_Servicing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/customize/uwf-servicing) WMI provider to invoke `UWF_Servicing.Enable`. This comes with an example powershell script to kick it off remotely:

```sh
# update with your remote computer name
$COMPUTER  = 'localhost'

# get the UWF WMI instance from the remote computer
$nextSession = Get-WMIObject -Computer $COMPUTER -n 'root\standardcimv2\embedded' -class UWF_Servicing |
  where CurrentSession -eq $false

# enable servicing mode
$nextSession.Enable() | Out-Null;
Write-Output "$COMPUTER is enabled for UWF servicing mode after the next restart."

# OR to disable servicing mode on next reboot instead:
# $nextSession.Disable()
```

Note: You need to use the newer `Get-CimInstance` in place of `Get-WMIObject` here in newer versions of powershell, but I haven't tested it

2. Use the [UnifiedWriteFilter CSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/unifiedwritefilter-csp) to change the `NextSession/ServicingEnabled` value and reboot. This option is probably more friendly with Endpoint Manager, but it's just a personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for your response we tried this and it say succeeded on endpoint manager but the device did not run servicing any idea why?

Comment: @JosephVictoria which one did you try, and how did you set it up in endpoint manager? For example, it looks like both of these just enable servicing for the next reboot - did you reboot the devices as well?

Comment: thank you for your response. I follow on what it said inhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/customize/uwf-servicing and deploy it thru end point manager script

Comment: well it runs one time but after one run it will not do it again

Comment: @JosephVictoria Can you clarify? When you say it runs one time, do you mean the script puts the device into servicing mode just once, or just for one reboot? What do you see if you manually run `Get-WmiObject -class UWF_Servicing` on the target device after the script runs?